# Where does one file bugreports?

Tags: release-loki

Installed Elementary OS Loki on the following configuration

Intel NUC6i7KYK, 16 GB memory, Samsung 850 EVO storage.

Install was smooth - no issues. Completely clean install, the system had no OS before the install.

App Center: Told me I had updates but clicking on update did not work for any item. Got the message "Waiting to be queued". I used apt-get after that for all new app installs and updates. Post updating all the apps now App Center freezes

Other than that it has been a smooth experience - nice light weight OS.

Where can I file bugs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view and submit bug reports [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos). I recommend searching the submitted reports before submitting a new one, because your issue might already have been documented.